# editButtonItemを使わずにTableViewをアニメーション付きで編集モードにしたい

Tags: swift, uitableview

以下のソースのように自作のナビゲーションバーのボタンからTableビューを編集モードに切り替えております。しかし、editButtonを使った時は編集モードになる、左に赤いボタンが出てくるアニメーションがありましたが、この方法だとなくなってしまいました。アニメーションを付ける方法はありますか？

```
let anotherButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Show", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "openMenu:")

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;

func openMenu(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    self.setEditing(editing, animated: true)

    editing = !editing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> self.setEditing(editing, animated: true)

この部分を以下のコードでアニメションがある編集モードになると思います

> self.tableView.setEditing(b animated:true)

Answer (score 0):

フラグを用意するのはどうでしょうか？

```
var flag = false

let anotherButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Show", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "openMenu:")

func openMenu(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
　if flag{
　　flag = false
　}else{
　　flag = true
　}
　self.tableView.setEditing(flag, animated: flag)
　tableView.isEditing = flag
}
```